# Make a div as heigh as needed

Tags: html, css

In my example below when the content in the top right `div` is too high, the content of the bottom `div` flows over the content of the top `div`.

I would like the top `div` to push the bottom `div` down so that content in both `div`s stays visible in the situation below.

How could I solve this?

```css
.left {
  background-color: grey;
  min-height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

.top {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 150px;
  
}

.bottom {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="top">
      top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/>top right<br/>top right<br/>top right<br/>

    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      bottom right
    </div>

  </div>

  <div>
```

### Edit

What I didn't mention before is that the bottom div should be on the bottom by default. This means that if there is enough space the bottom line of the bottom `div` should align with the bottom line of the left `div`

Comment: Try changing `height: 150px;` to`min-height: 150px`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a flex `row` layout for the outer elements and `column` layout for the right side. Setting `.top` and `.bottom` to `flex-grow: 1` will cause them to grow to match the parent height if there is not enough content for them to stretch to the parent height

```css
.left {
  background-color: grey;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.top {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.bottom {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
/* added these */
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.top,.bottom {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper flex">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="right flex col">
    <div class="top">
      top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/>top right<br/>top right<br/>top right<br/>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      bottom right
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I was not looking for a solution with flex since then I have to change a lot on my site over here.

Comment: @sanders you're welcome. Be sure to put details like that in your post so we don't waste one another's time with solutions that aren't helpful. Why would you have to change a lot? What's the end goal exactly? Doesn't seem like your example is an accurate representation of the problem itself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand your reaction. Sorry about that I only found out that I didn't put enough information after I played around with the solutions. The content in the top div can be different each time as it gets filled with content coming back from an API Call.

Comment: @sanders no worries, but you should add those details your post. You haven't chosen a solution so people may still answer.

Comment: @sanders "The content in the top div can be different each time as it gets filled with content coming back from an API Call." How is that relevant to anything? I'm assuming that has something to do with what you're looking for as a solution, but you haven't said anything about why that's relevant, so it doesn't clarify anything for me. I may still be able to help out if you give further clarification on what it is you're trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because, you have given a fixed `height` of `150px`to the `.top` div, due to which it does not resize itself as the content inside it increases.

```
.top {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 150px;
}
```

To solve it, just change the value of `height` to `auto` or give it a `min-height` of `150px` instead of a fixed one.
**Like this:**

```
.top {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: auto;
}
```

**Or this:**

```
.top {
  background-color: lightblue;
  min-height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here attached is a snippet showing what you want to achieve. Getting the left div to grow with the parent would however maybe need a little javascript *(but that's not part of the question anyways)*. Cheers

```css
.left {
  background-color: grey;
  min-height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

.top {
  background-color: lightblue;
  
  /* changes here */
  min-height: 150px;
  height: auto;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="top">
      top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/>top right<br/>top right<br/>top right<br/>

    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      bottom right
    </div>

  </div>

  <div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With this there is one problem. That is when there is not so much content  in the top div. The content of the bottom div goes all the way up. But what I want the bottom div to be on the bottom by default and be pushed down when the content in the top div grows.

Answer (score 0):

You have a height specified in px on the `.top` div.  take this out and your div will adjust its height to fit its content

```
.top {
  background-color: lightblue;
  }
```

```css
.left {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

.top {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="top">
      top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/>top right<br/>top right<br/>top right<br/>

    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      bottom right
    </div>

  </div>

  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you wanted a fixed height for your content.

The snippet I show you here as an alternative asks you to set the height only in the wrapper so it's easier to mantain, the top right div takes the height it needs and the bottom right adapts takes the remaining height from the parent

```
    html, body{
      height: 100%;
    }
    .wrapper {
      height: 200px;
    }
    .left {
      background-color: grey;
      float: left;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .right {
      height: auto;
      float: left;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .top {
      background-color: lightblue;
      height: 166px;
      
    }

    .bottom {
      background-color: lightgreen;
      height: calc(100% - 166px);
    }
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="left">
        left
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <div class="top">
          top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/> top right<br/>top right<br/>top right<br/>top right<br/>

        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          bottom right
        </div>

      </div>

      <div>
```